# Different delete result by the same function

Tags: sql, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data

I'm removing object in loop by using Crud repository delete function. My object have relation which also should be removed with it (orphanRemoval) + cascadeType = ALL. 
But I noticed that first iteration removes object correctly with relations and this sql looks:

```
    Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        base_interval_last_modifications 
    where
        base_interval_id=?
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        visit 
    where
        id=?
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        last_modification 
    where
        id=?
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        base_interval 
    where
        id=?
```

Second iteration produces this sql statement:

```
Hibernate: 
delete 
from
    visit 
where
    id=?
```

Could someone explain me how its possible that the same function on the same type of object generates another statement and in fact doesnt remove all relations correctly?

UPDATE "more code":
In first loop baseInterval is removed correctly and workInterval is untouched but in second loop only visit is removed without baseInterval.

```
@Entity
class Visit(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Int? = null,

    @OneToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn
    var baseInterval: BaseInterval? = null,
)

@Entity
class BaseInterval(
    id: Int? = null,
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "baseInterval")
    var visit: Visit? = null,

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    var workInterval: WorkInterval? = null
)
```

Loop

```
futureVisits
            .forEach {
                visitRepository.delete(it)
                }
```

Comment: could you post the rest of the code: entities + the call to delete function

Comment: @Elgayed I've posted most important code which probably needs a fix

Comment: did you check that the 2nd visit object has a BaseInterval

Comment: yes it has. It looks almost like first but has another id.